# Can I get a list of Public Ip Addresses that the bq tool may use to import into Big Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

I use a Proxy to use the bq tool to import data into bigquery, but my Proxy requires that i specify both the domain and all potential public IP addresses that it will need to allow out.   I have it set to allow the googleapis.com and google.com domain, but for some reason the bq tool seems to connect often directly to an IP.  Therefore I need to specify each of those IPs in the Proxy configuration to be able to connect to Bigquery.   Currently the list of IPs I am using is 74.125.133.95, 74.125.142.92, and 74.125.133.84.  I know this can change and there may be more IPs that it connects to.  Is it possible to get a range or list of IPs that I can put into my proxy configuration so I do not get interrupted uploads when the IP changes due to load balancing, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As with all Google APIs, it is not possible to provide a list of IP addresses or IP address ranges for the BigQuery API. Google's API have a range of IP adresses that are dynamic and change to accommodate changes in demand.